# Leverage AWS Amplify to authenticate to a DynamoDB via REST?

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, authentication, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I'm an AWS Amplify newbie.  I am actually a AWS DynamoDB newbie.  And Cognito. Etc. (I have a tiny bit more experience with IAM if that helps - I don't need S3 buckets, etc., for this work).

I need the ability to authenticate via a command line.  No UI component in any form, React, Angular, Vue, or anything.  And I'm not finding documentation on how to do this - which could just mean I'm not using the right search term(s) Or just an issue of not having tried checking if ChatGPT 3 can just write me something, and therefore not being in the year 2023.

I have seen quite a few examples of UI components with logins, all using Components such as React, etc.  In other works, no help for a "command line utility" that has no need for help from a browser - unless I have no other choice for this work.  Note:  This does not help if you want to invoke using your own cron implementation outside the AWS framework (I did see that capability).

I have the utility working the way I want, which is automating database population.  The API is REST.  However, I obviously am not an authenticated user when I run it.  So for development, I have given unauthenticated users full CRUD access to the DynamoDb tables I'm working with - and it's working as far as I have it.  Obviously, this is not the way I want to interact with the tool outside of my development and internal testing.  Note:  I do have other parts of this system reading this populated table via React and GraphQL - and there are other tables I'm not populating so that's being implemented in the standard Amplify manner - and that's working.  However, it seemed that this more old-skool approach made sense for an automated db populator where this custom command line tool was the only place where write access was needed, and it's definitely a place where a more RDBMS approach seemed to make sense.

So: How would I approach this, authenticating to Dynamo tables from a terminal/command-line implementation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For this you don't need Amplify, you simply need to call Cognito from the CLI.

For example

```
aws get-credentials-for-identity
--identity-id <>
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cognito-identity/get-credentials-for-identity.html

Comment: From what I've found so far, this looks like a good starting point, needing further digging.

1.  The link is for v1.  'get-credentials-for-identity' is not present for v2.

2.  That's ok, I'm looking to do this programmatically anyway within my tool command (written in TypeScript, leveraging nodeJS).  And the above points to the API itself, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetCredentialsForIdentity.html.

I'm now getting "Missing Authentication Token", which means I apparently need to learn and call the AWS Security Token service (I'm a AWS newbie).